# using Spoon Virtual Application Studio

Tags: deployment, virtualization

when I try to build a DOTNET application using Spoon VAS it downloads the required DOTNET runtime every time. Are there any way to save the framework files locally without the need to download those everytime I build the application. Also the application uses a VistaDB embedded database. Can I embed the database file inside the virtualized application so that all that I get is one exe to be distributed to the client?

Answer (score 1):

You can embed the VistaDB libraries in your application using ILMerge.  In general that "just works" but there are cases where you have to slightly modify configuration files (e.g. app.config files) where there are fully qualified names.  If you run into any issues just contact Gibraltar Support.